# Node.JS http get request returns undefined

Tags: node.js, httprequest, http-proxy

This was supposed to be pretty simple but instead of getting the data back I am getting undefined.

I am behind a proxy server and I am not good at making requests from behind a proxy server. I found just one tutorial which explained http requests when using a proxy server without using an external module and that didn't explain properly.

```
const http = require('http');
let options = {
    host: '10.7.0.1',
    port:8080,
    path:'www.google.co.uk'
}

http.get(options,(res) => {
    let str = '';
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    str += chunk;
})

res.on('end', (str) => {
    console.log(str);
    })
})
```

10.7.0.1 is the address of the proxy server and 8080 is the port.

The output of this code is undefined.

I don't even know if the method is correct and I am not able to figure it out.I read the node http docs and wrote the options object to  the best of my understanding , correct me if I am wrong.

And in general how do i make requests when behind a proxy server.

Comment: please see the update and let me know if it works :) @Daksh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request` package allows to make an `http` request in a pretty elegant way, and for specifying proxy, just need to set the value for `proxy` key inside the options object request takes as an argument.

```
const request = require('request');

request({url: 'http://example.com', proxy: 'https://host:port'}, (error, response, body) => {
  //Do whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Important**

If you want to connect to a proxy using http, please see this, you need to use connect method

```
const options = {
    port: 8080,
    hostname: '10.7.0.1',
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'www.google.com:80'
  };

  const req = http.request(options);
  req.end();

  req.on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
console.log('got connected!');

socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
             'Host: www.google.com:80\r\n' +
             'Connection: close\r\n' +
             '\r\n');
socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});
socket.on('end', () => {
  proxy.close();
}
```

**EXTRA INFORMATION** (not needed)

Here is a full code I have found off [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) on how to create proxies and making requests behind them. It is basically creating a server and making a request over it.

```
const http = require('http');
const net = require('net');
const url = require('url');

// Create an HTTP tunneling proxy
const proxy = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('okay');
});
proxy.on('connect', (req, cltSocket, head) => {
  // connect to an origin server
  const srvUrl = url.parse(`http://${req.url}`);
  const srvSocket = net.connect(srvUrl.port, srvUrl.hostname, () => {
    cltSocket.write('HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n' +
                    'Proxy-agent: Node.js-Proxy\r\n' +
                    '\r\n');
    srvSocket.write(head);
    srvSocket.pipe(cltSocket);
    cltSocket.pipe(srvSocket);
  });
});

// now that proxy is running
proxy.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', () => {

  // make a request to a tunneling proxy
  const options = {
    port: 1337,
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'www.google.com:80'
  };

  const req = http.request(options);
  req.end();

  req.on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
    console.log('got connected!');

    // make a request over an HTTP tunnel
    socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
                 'Host: www.google.com:80\r\n' +
                 'Connection: close\r\n' +
                 '\r\n');
    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk.toString());
    });
    socket.on('end', () => {
      proxy.close();
    });
  });
});
```

It is creating a server via `http.createServer()` then starts listening with `proxy.listen()` after they are done, it connects by using http's `connect` method, and writes on socket a simple get request, and sends it to google as it was the specified path.

Comment: Thanks, but I got plenty of tutorials on google which explained making requests using external modules but I want to do the same using Node's standard modules.

Comment: to make a request behind a proxy with http module, you need to set the proxy with using that command, is that what you are looking for? @Daksh

Comment: @Daksh please see my update, I think I have found a solution. I had hard time understanding your question, I am sorry. You need to use the connect method, and specify the path. here is an example. :)

Comment: I think you've got it wrong , I don't want to create a proxy server . Let me elaborate => I am in a university and it uses a proxy server (like most universities do ) I made a simple http get request and I got undefined instead of the data , and i am not sure if its happening because of the proxy or not , plus i want a general way to make http requests in such a scenario.

Comment: then only see the code that's above, it is pretty much self explanatory, if you have any question, okay so tell me what you have on `10.7.0.1` ? @Daksh